# SFTP isn't working through unix shell script

Tags: sftp

I am trying to do sftp through a unix shell script and getting the error

```
Host key verification failed. Connection closed
```

However when I do sftp manually like below, its working

```
sftp -b batch_file user@remoteserver
```

`batch_file` contains `lcd`, `cd` and `put` commands.

Script:

```
#get inputs parameters
file=$1
dir=$2
sftp_node=$3
dest_dir=$4
dol=$

original_dir='eval echo $dol$dir'
dest_dir='eval echo $dol$dest_dir'

cd $original_dir
sfile='ls -lt ${file}* | head -1'

#To execute sftp in batch mode

rm $SCRIPTDIR/sftp_batch_file.txt

echo "lcd $original_dir" > $SCRIPTDIR/sftp_batch_file.txt
echo "cd $dest_dir" >> $SCRIPTDIR/sftp_batch_file.txt
echo "put $sfile " >> $SCRIPTDIR/sftp_batch_file.txt

sftp -oPort=56050 -b $SCRIPTDIR/sftp_batch_file.txt user@servername
s=$?

if [ $s -eq 0]
then 
echo "$original_dir/$sfile sent to $dest_dir/$sfile  on server"
exit 0
fi
```

**Manual run Log:**

OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server [123.456.789.000] port 12345.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SFTP Server
debug1: no match: SFTP Server
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_3732' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_3732' not found

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '[server]':12345 is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
sftp> lcd 
sftp> cd  
sftp> put filename
Uploading filename to /filename
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 4832, received 2696 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 8159.3, received 4552.4
debug1: Exit status 0

**Script run Log:**

OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: init_func_ptrs success
debug1: Value of krb5 is 1
debug1: Value of gssapi is 1
debug1: Connecting to server [123.456.789.000] port 12345.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SFTP Server
debug1: no match: SFTP Server
debug1: Authenticating to server:12345 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-cbc MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-cbc MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<8192<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:U2JlOXEu69uw4l+TGqDBRxnaH+Mjf12WeHc4IGd6lcI
debug1: checking without port identifier
Host key verification failed.
Connection closed

Please help me to identify and fix the issue.

Comment: If you expect an answer, you should provide more details.

Comment: When you *"do sftp manually"*, you do not use `-oPort=56050`.

Comment: if i don't see oPort, it throws error as that port# is onlu allowed. even manually, i used oPort

Comment: So edit your question to show that. There's no `oPort` in your manual command in the question.

Comment: Also add `-v` switch to both manual and script `sftp` and show us their output.

Comment: Updated my question with the -v logs. Please check. I see there are some differences

Comment: Are you even running it manually and in a script on the *same machine*? Because each run uses a different version of OpenSSH.

Comment: Yeh, I found that difference in Versions. However, I am running on the same machine both manually or script.  Will it make any difference with .sh and .ksh scripts ?

Comment: What do you get from `which sftp` in shell and in script?

Comment: Yeah..! I checked again now. the machines are different and the shebang line also needed a correction.

Answer (score 0):

how do you authenticate with the server? sftp batch mode can't work with interactive authentication methods (it wan't prompt for user and password, you must supply credentials on the command line)

if your sftp uses password run:

```
sftp -b batch_file user:password@remoteserver
```

Comment: I wanted to do the sftp without hard-coding the password in the script. I changed my script like this      sftp user@server << EOF; lcd source_dir ; cd dest_dir; put file; EOF